# Ajax post not received by php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have written a simple code. In order to avoid flooding a JSON server, i want to break up the JSON response in pieces. So my jquery code should be parsing one variable ("page") to the php page that handles the JSON Oauth Request. On success, it should append the DIV with the latest responses.

My code should be working, except for the fact that my ajax post is not being received by my php file.

Here goes

archief.html

```
$("#klik").click(function() {
console.log("fire away");
page = page + 1;
$("#archief").load("trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php");
 console.log(page);              
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php",
                   data:  page,
                    success: function() {

                            console.log(page);

                          $.get("trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php", function(archief) {
                                $('#archief').append(archief);
                            });

                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                            alert(err.responseText);
                    } 
                });
                return false;
       });
```

The php file doesn't receive anything.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

gives me `array(0) { }`.

Very strange, i'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: where is the php part of your code?

Comment: Try with:: data: "&page=" + page OR 

data: {'page' : + page},

Comment: value is not posted to "trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php",

Answer (score 3):

You are sending a string instead of key-value pairs. If you want to use `$_POST` you need to send key-value pairs:

```
...
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php",
  data:  { 'page': page },
  success: function() {
     ...
```

If you send a single value or string, you would need to read the raw input.

Also, you are sending 2 GET requests and 1 POST request to the same file. Is that intentional? Note that only the POST request will have the `$_POST` variable set.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help and not letting me post "this still doens't work" posts :)

I made the mistake of loading the "unConsulted" php file [$.get("trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php"] upon success. Instead, i append the response of the PHP.

The working code below:

```
$("#klik").click(function() {
console.log("fire away");
page = page + 1;

//$("#archief").load("trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php");
 console.log(page);              
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "trytocombinenewageandgettagsendates.php",
                   data:  { 'page': page },

                    success: function(response){

                    $("#archief").append(response);  

                    },

                    error: function(err) {
                            alert(err.responseText);
                    } 
                });
                return false;
```